# SQL запрос в postgresql по select

Tags: sql, postgresql

Надо выбрать

```
 select distinct type_id from t1
```

и сделать join из полученных результатов type_id = id

```
 select name from t2 where id = (полученные результаты с первого select)
```

Еще если возможно сделать вывод только name. Первый select чтобы не выводился. Не силен в sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужен тут join. Почти прямо так и пишется запрос:

```
select name from t2 where id in (select distinct type_id from t1)
```

Comment: При таком подходе на больших объемах в таблице t2 могут быть проблемы с производительностью. Зачастую `join` все же лучше, чем `in`.

Comment: Не претендую на опытного DBA, но по моему опыту на проектах с небольшими таблицами (порядка десятков миллионов строк) in subquery давал более простой и быстрый план запроса, чем аналогичный по результату join. pg9.4

Comment: Многое зависит от СУБД. Я в основном работаю с Oracle, его планировщик чаще всего такие запросы перепишет все равно и план будет такой же, как и через джоин. Но когда запрос получается в 200 строк, то планировщик уже сдается и может получиться не самый оптимальнй запрос. Это вопрос из разряда как научишься, так и пишешь потом. Я сторонник, что лучше сразу учиться не писать подзапросы, там где в них нет особой необходимости

Comment: Не сказал бы, что многое. Скорее всё зависит от субд. И не только от субд, но ещё и от версии субд. Для postgresql 9.4, как уже сказал, и explain и explain analyze (т.е. план и косты реального выполнения запроса) для подзапроса дешевле. В том же mysql - он вовсе долгое время не умел различать subquery от correlated subquery в where и всегда делал связанный подзапрос, поэтому там делались только джойны. Не нужно запоминать один подход из-за поведения одной базы и затем его аксиоматично применять всюду.

Comment: Хмм...С ходу не могу понять, как план для подзапроса получается дешевле. Быстрое загугливание ответа не дало. Если знаете, что можно почитать на эту тему, подскажите. В любом случае, я учту ваш опыт. Спасибо!